# Includes in ERB for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, include, erb

I am trying to follow this guide:  http://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts

Chris states to inject the svg just after the opening body tag. In PHP this is simple but i'm using Rails so have an .html.erb file.

How do I include the file using this? I have tried asset helpers, evaluate, render. Nothing seems to work?

Comment: Try this https://gist.github.com/tomeara/6515860

Comment: you should put this as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This belongs to Ruby Racer.

**inline_svg_helper.rb**

```
def inline_svg(path)
    File.open("app/assets/images/#{path}", "rb") do |file|
    raw file.read
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`<%= image_tag 'file.svg' %>` didn't seem to work on Chrome browser, so I tried `render` to include svg file in following way, and it worked to me.

```
<%= render inline: (render file: Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'file.svg')) %>
```

And I have another question, is it a good (or safe) way?

Comment: I found I didn't need the `render inline:`, just `render file:` worked fine.